# How do I create a table with all the rows under ScheduledDate being the same date 9/21/2018?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting a syntax error in my field definition.

```
CREATE TABLE Sept21(
OrderNum INT, 
TaskID VARCHAR(5), 
Description VARCHAR(50), 
ScheduledDate DATE,
QuotedPrice DECIMAL(15, 2)
);
INSERT INTO Sept21(ScheduledDate)
VALUES('9/21/2018');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every row in the table to have the value `9/21/2018` for the column `ScheduledDate`, you should use a constraint. In your case, you want to [`CHECK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) that a value meets some criteria before inserting the row.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Sept21(
  OrderNum INT, 
  TaskID VARCHAR(5), 
  Description VARCHAR(50), 
  ScheduledDate DATE,
  QuotedPrice DECIMAL(15, 2),
  CONSTRAINT ScheduledDateIsSept21In2018 CHECK (ScheduledDate = '9/21/2018')
);
```

This will ensure that a row cannot be inserted into your table unless the `CHECK` constraint's criteria are met.

For example, the following `INSERT` statement would pass the `CHECK` constraint and the row would be inserted into the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO Sept21 VALUES
(123, 'ABCDE', 'Some Description', '2018-09-21', 15.5);
```

While this `INSERT` statement would fail (because the date doesn't meet the `CHECK` constraint's criteria) and the row would not be inserted:

```sql
INSERT INTO Sept21 VALUES
(123, 'ABCDE', 'Some Description', 'Mar 13, 2019', 15.5)
```

You can see for yourself with [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ead63/9).

Comment: Would you also know why I got the syntax error in my field description?

Comment: Not with the information currently in the question. Could you please add details about how you got the error and what the error message said? [Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02b07/1) showing that you can create the table and insert a row containing only the `ScheduledDate` without getting an error.